# How do I hide the link to the RSS feed on the term page?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, 8, feeds

I want to keep the feed functionality, but I want to hide the "Subscribe to [term name]" link on the term page.

Answer (score 10):

Under "Structure", "Views", open the "Taxonomy term" view, on the `Feed display`, under `Feed settings` set `Attach to` to none.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to hide RSS feed icon.